# Async calls in Prism.Forms

Tags: asynchronous, xamarin, async-await, prism

I have some async services that I would like to call in different places in Xamarin application. I port my code from native UWP app with Prism.

Some time ago I was able to do this by declaring making methods like

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
```

or

```
public override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
```

used await there. However, it stopped working.

Trying to use GetAwaiter().GetResult() blocks execution and results in deadlock.

This is kind of weird, considering that INavigationService.NavigateAsync itself is async method, but samples suggest to use in OnInitialized without any await, which I believe is wrong.

So, does anyone have a suggestion how to proper make async calls in Prism.Forms?

Answer (score 1):

`OnNavigatedTo` gets called from the UI thread (it is part of the UI Lifecycle). If you block inside that method, you will of course have a deadlock.

Just because `NavigateAsync` returns a Task and has an async name, doesn't mean everything in that method happens on another thread. It just means it usually does something, that you could wait for.

The problem here is, that `OnNavigatedTo` is returning `void`, so it will return to the caller, once you have an await in there. That doesn't stop you from using it, you just cant **block** there.

```
public override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
{
    // do sync stuff
    await DoSomethingAsync();
    // this happens after all the other lifecycle methods
}
```

Just be aware, that everything after the await just happens after the whole navigation is done. And that exceptions thrown in there will not show up (it's basically fire and forget).

You can always make the continuation explicit by not using async/await and using `.ContinueWith(...)` instead.

Comment: This is exactly how it worked for me before. But I didn't touch Android part for few months, maybe made couple upgrades through nugget, and now the way you describe gives me unhandled exceptions. To be specific, I use SQLite, and it breaks when I await async code. When I replace exactly same line with sync call, it works.

Comment: One more thing, this approach works for me in UWP app, it's Xamarin where I have the problem.

Comment: What exceptions exactly? It's mostly due to calling Task.Result somewhere, which you should almost never do.

Comment: It crashes so bad, that I can't even catch exception. The issue with OnNavigatedTo seems to go away after I updated to latest version of SQLite, don't know it it was related, but I still have problem with PrismApplication.OnInitialized. There it crashed miserably without even catching exception.

Currently I found solution by just starting this thing in new thread, so what I did is this:
TaskFactory.StartNew(()=>
{
   try
  {
    <my async method>().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
{
   ... handling exception
}
}

This code did the trick.